# Read child prop of unknown parent

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to access the value of a prop, but the parent prop is a randomly generated number.

If this were a simple array, it would be something like `this.props.photos[0].url` but unfortunately it doesn't seem that simple. How do I get the value of the url?

Here is my code :

```
imagedetails={this.props.thought.photos}
```

I've tried `props.children.url`, `props.children[0].url`, etc.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. So, is parent prop Array or Number? Also, could you put here more of your code in order for us to see what is exactly the problem?

Comment: Please provide more details like the components and data.